# Is there a way to prevent Show Password functionality in another Android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, passwords, android-autofill-manager

I am designing an android autofill service, and one of its features is that it shouldn't allow the user to see the password content it fills in any app because the password doesn't originate from the user. However, most apps have Show Password functionality in their password text fields. I have thought of programmatically pressing the enter key on the keypad as soon as the autofill service fills the password field, that way the user gets logged into the app without seeing the password. I'd like to know if this approach could work and if not, what other approaches I could take?

Comment: A password autofill service that doesn't require me to know my passwords is great (as long as it stores them securely and is trustworthy); a password autofill service that doesn't allow me to know my passwords is terrible and I can't imagine ever using such a thing.

Comment: @David Conrad, I explicitly stated that the passwords do not originate from the user. They aren't your passwords

Comment: They absolutely are my passwords. They're passwords to access my accounts on various apps, right? This is exactly how Google's password service works when it generates passwords for you, except of course it allows you to see your passwords, not only on the web pages or apps where it enters them for you, but on passwords.google.com. Just because I used a tool to generate the password for me doesn't me it is not my password.

Comment: I can't remember mentioning that it generates passwords like Google's password service

Comment: You could've just asked me to explain better if the question wasn't clear

Comment: It doesn't generate them for the user, but it doesn't get them from the user, and it autofills them into other apps that aren't under your control? I guess I should have, because it is very unclear how it can know the password for the other apps. I highly doubt what you're asking for is possible, but good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227391/discussion-between-israel-and-david-conrad).